# C# overwriting current line in console not working in conhost.exe

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, console

I have a console application that runs a task that reports it's completion percent as it progresses. While doing this, I display a progress bar to the console. I use `Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);` before calling `Console.Write` to update the current line so that the progress bar updates in place.

When I run this in Powershell using Windows Terminal it behaves just how I want it to. Each update overwrites the current line. The problem is if I run the application from Powershell in the (legacy) conhost.exe it doesn't overwrite the line. The output is:

```
[        ][  0%]
[=       ][  1%]
[=       ][  2%]
```

... and so on. Here is a complete program that exhibits this behavior:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Progress<int> progress = new Progress<int>();
    progress.ProgressChanged += Progress_ProgressChanged;

    IProgress<int> reporter = progress;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        reporter.Report(i);
    }
}

private static void Progress_ProgressChanged(object? sender, int e)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.Write(GetProgressString(e));
}

private static string GetProgressString(int progress)
{
    // Total width of the progress meter.
    // Console width minus "[][100%]".
    int width = Console.WindowWidth - 8;
    double progressDec = (double)progress / 100;
    int numChars = (int)(progressDec * width);

    StringBuilder meterBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < numChars; i++)
    {
        meterBuilder.Append('=');
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (width - numChars); i++)
    {
        meterBuilder.Append(' ');
    }

    return $"[{meterBuilder}][{string.Format("{0, 3}", progress)}%]";
}
```

Is there a different approach to doing this that will work in the old Windows console host?

Comment: How about from a `cmd.exe` prompt, or spawning the EXE from a GUI window (e.g. double-click it in Windows Explorer) so that a fresh console object is created?  Is it only when PowerShell is involved that's the problem?

Comment: And in the failing scenario, is `Console.WindowWidth` also coming back with a bogus value?  Your example output doesn't look like it is correctly filling the width.

Comment: One really simple thing to try: use `int width = Console.WindowWidth - 10;` instead of 8, so you don't actually hit the end of the line and potentially wrap.

Comment: @BenVoigt Changing it to 10 fixes it. But what are the 2 extra characters that are causing a wrap? I'm not writing any newlines out.

Comment: There are no extra characters.  The two terminals evidently differ in what happens when the current position actually hits the end of the line.  That is, if your window is 60 characters wide and you write exactly 60 characters, the cursor position of one is (row: N: column: 60) -- which is an illegal column index -- and the other is (row: N+1, column: 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code overwrites the current line just fine -- but in the failing case, "the current line" is not what you think it is.

If you don't want to advance the row, don't write to the very last column, because the cursor position has to be *after* what you wrote, and some terminals will wrap it to the next line proactively.

Alternatively, you could save the value of `CursorTop` before you write (before the cursor position has a chance to overflow to the next line).

You already are not playing well with any other concurrent console output, because you overwrite whatever is on the current line whether it was generated by the progress bar or not.  Saving the Y-coordinate where you actually wrote might improve on that (but you'd also need to restore the cursor position after you update the progress bar, or else other output would repeatedly replace the line after the progress bar instead of properly accumulating).

Answer (score 2):

To **complement [Ben Voigt's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76008352/45375)**, which explains the underlying problem and points to solutions, by spelling out concrete solutions:

Note:

- The following only fix your immediate problem, but, as noted in Ben's answer, it wouldn't help if other console output were to produce console output in parallel, which would interfere with the progress bar.

---

Given Ben's explanation of the cause - writing to the *last* column of a row automatically advancing `Console.CursorTop` to the next row in *some* terminals - you can simply **shorten your progress bar so as not to write to the *last* column** to avoid this problem, which in your case simply means:

```
// 8 -> 9
int width = Console.WindowWidth - 9;
```

Additionally, you could do away with the `Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);` statement if you placed `\r`, i.e. a CR at the start of the string you return from `GetProgressString()`

```
// Note the \r at the start
return $"\r[{meterBuilder}][{string.Format("{0, 3}", progress)}%]";
```

The `\r` effectively achieves what `Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop)` is meant to do: it sets the cursor back to the *first* column on the *same row*.

Note:

- In macOS terminals and in Windows Terminal this works even *without* ensuring that the last column isn't being written to - unlike in `conhost.exe` (regular console windows) on Windows.

  - That this works in macOS terminals (as of .NET 7.0.5) actually smells like a *bug*, because while `Console.CursorTop` *does* advance to the next row when the last column is being written to (as in `conhost.exe` consoles on Windows, but unlike in Windows Terminal), prepending a subsequent string passed to `Console.Write()` with `\r` somehow still manages to write to the original row - see [GitHub issue #84808](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/84808).
- As Ben points out, nonstandard terminal configurations can interfere with this approach (modify the behavior of CR) - see his comment below.

Comment: Behavior of `\r` alone is also terminal-dependent.  And it won't help if the cursor advanced to the next line.  So it's misleading to present these as alternatives.  As well, the concrete solution that actually works was already proposed in a comment.

Comment: Real terminal emulators are configurable, e.g. https://community-assets.home-assistant.io/original/3X/a/b/ab75bc2703e1c82ee00a41104b4cefe5e94efe7f.png  Note "implicit LF in every CR" option.

Comment: I said "the concrete solution was already proposed in a comment" not answer.  That one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76008136/c-sharp-overwriting-current-line-in-console-not-working-in-conhost-exe/76008468?noredirect=1#comment134054942_76008136

Comment: @BenVoigt, good point - I totally missed the comments.

Comment: (@BenVoigt - and the fact that I did miss the solution in the _comments_ suggests that it's always better to showcase solutions in _answers_).

Comment: I don't disagree, but I feel the explanation is likely to help future readers, while changing one literal number in the question code isn't.

Comment: I agree that the explanation is helpful, which is why I (a) prominently point to your answer and (b) state that my answer _complements_ yours. True, with the loss of `\r` as a true alternative my answer has become less useful, but I feel it may still be of interest to some - including the aspect of focusing on the simple fix that was buried in the comments.

Comment: @BenVoigt, as for the puzzling macOS behavior: I think I've isolated a bug - see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/84808. I've also updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: That's some nice sleuthing